# how to merge two partitions that one of their size can not be changed?

Tags: macos, disk-utility, mojave, partition

I have created a linux partition and used it for a while. Now I erased it and I want to add this partition to my macosx partition. However, the partition that includes Macosx says that "The size of this partition cannot be changed.".

Is there any way without losing my data in macosx and merge those 2 partitions?

You can find SS below:

[image]

[image]

And `diskutil list` :

[image]

Comment: There is something wrong in your list diskutil : the partition/Container 97 go is fffff ffff and seem reconnized later as a valid container. Can you reboot your Mac and give the result (in text mode) of the `diskutil list internal ` command?

Comment: @Jean_JD: What you are asking for can not be accomplished. The moment the Mac is restarted, all of the volumes on `disk1` will not be accessible.

Comment: Can you, after boot in Recovery Mode, give the results of the terminal command : `gpt -r show disk0` ?

Comment: @David Where is the problem? I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: @Jean_JD: Since the partition containing macOS is not the APFS type in the GPT, the Mac can not restart (reboot) back to macOS or to the internal macOS Recovery.

Comment: @David yes, I understand, but it's impossible modify gpt table on the active system. So the internet recovery mode can help.

Comment: Impossible do to SIP being enabled. You could if SIP was disabled. I am not suggesting this as part of a solution to the current question. Yes, internet recovery mode can help. I would first ask the OP to post the offset and size of `disk0s2`. You could then post an answer instructing the OP to boot to internet recovery mode, then enter the commands to fix the problem.

Comment: One thing I don't understand: this is by deleting from linux, I guess, and this is not the first time that a Linux partition deletion (on Linux) has killed the APFS container / partition, which is in between parentheses, a real Linux bug, that we end up with an HS container. On the other hand, if we look at the listing coming from diskutil list, the contents of the system container are indeed present while the container itself is represented by FFFFFFFFFFFF. For me, the OP had to restart Mac OS X after the Linux bug was done.

Comment: The OP used macOS to erase the Linux partition, then posted the output from the `diskutil list` command. The Mac was not restarted.

Comment: @David. Are you sure? Mac Os x kill himself his apfs structure? I have a doubt.

Comment: Yes, I am sure. I tested by creating a Mojave and Ubuntu dual boot arrangement in a virtual machine. The drive was hybrid partitioned with the MBR partition table containing 3 partitions of type `EE`, `DA` and `83`. I used the Disk Utility application while booted to Mojave to erase the Linux partition and create a new APFS container with a single volume. The error described by the OP occurred.

Answer (score 1):

While this type of question has been asked and answered many times here at Ask Different, I have not found a previous question which matched your configuration. So, I might as well post a new answer.

> Note: This answer assumes the `Ek` volume does not contain any important data. If so, then post a comment.

1. Boot to [macOS Recovery over the Internet](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201314) or an [USB flash drive macOS installer](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201372). Once booted to macOS Recovery or a macOS installer, open a Terminal application window.

   Note: The Terminal application can be found under "Utilities" on the menu bar.
2. Enter the command shown below. If you are using an older version of macOS Recovery or an older macOS installer, then may need to omit the `internal` argument.

   ```
   diskutil list internal
   ```

   From the output, determine the identifier for the internal drive. In this answer, the identifier is assumed to be `disk1`. If your internal drive has been assigned a different identifier, then make the appropriate substitutions in the remaining steps. Enter the command below to set the `disk` variable to the identifier of the internal drive.

   ```
   disk=disk1
   ```
3. Determine if the MBR partition table may contain undesired partition entries by entering the command given below.

   ```
   gpt -r show $disk >/dev/null
   ```

   If you do **not** get the message show below, then proceed to step 4.

   ```
   gpt show: disk1: Suspicious MBR at sector 0
   ```

   Enter the command below to edit the MBR partition table.

   ```
   fdisk -e /dev/$disk
   ```

   A message similar to the one shown below will appear. You can ignore this message. (The message means macOS does not include MBR BIOS boot code.)

   ```
   fdisk: could not open MBR file /usr/standalone/i386/boot0: No such file or directory
   ```

   The `fdisk` has entered an interactive input mode. Enter the input show below to remove any undesired partition entries.

   ```
   s 2
   0
   s 3
   0
   s 4
   0
   w
   y
   q
   ```
4. Enter the commands below to remove the partition encompassing the APFS volume labeled `Ek`.

   > Note: Usually, a `diskutil unmountdisk $disk` command needs to be entered just before using a `gpt` command that writes to the internal drive.

   ```
   read b x < <(gpt -r show $disk | grep 7C34)
   diskutil unmountdisk $disk
   gpt remove -b $b $disk
   ```
5. (Optional) There is an `Apple_Boot` type partition which I believe is not needed. You can enter the commands below to remove this partition.

   ```
   read b x < <(gpt -r show $disk | grep 426F)
   diskutil unmountdisk $disk
   gpt remove -b $b $disk
   ```
6. Change the GUID partition type of FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFFFFFFFFFF to the correct value.

   ```
   read b s i t < <(gpt -r show $disk | grep FFFF)
   diskutil unmountdisk $disk
   gpt remove -b $b $disk
   diskutil unmountdisk $disk
   gpt add -i $i -b $b -s $s -t apfs $disk
   ```

   If you are using an older version of macOS Recovery or an older macOS installer, then you may get the error message shown below when entering the last command shown above.

   ```
   usage: gpt add [-b lba] [-i index] [-s lba] [-t uuid] device ...
   ```

   If you get the message shown above, then enter the alternate version shown below.

   ```
   diskutil unmountdisk $disk
   gpt add -i $i -b $b -s $s -t 7C3457EF-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC $disk
   ```
7. Restart to macOS.
8. Use the Disk Utility application or enter the command below to reclaim the free space.

   ```
   diskutil apfs resizecontainer disk0s2 0
   ```

   Performing this step will also clean up the partition tables if necessary in the following ways

   - Removing any remaining hybrid partitioning from the MBR partition table.
   - Reordering the GPT partition entries in ascending order.